# Font size rem doesn't scale on different screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, font-size

Fonts and elements don't scale when the screen size is reduced. Following is the code. In the developer tools if I change the root HTML font size, the font's and respective elements scale but when the screen size is reduced it doesn't.

```css
/*
    COLORS:
    
    Light green: #7ed56f
    Medium green: #55c57a
    Dark green: #28b485
    font-grey: #777777
    
    */

* *::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.7;
  color: #777777;
  padding: 3rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  height: 95vh;
  /*95% of screen*/
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right bottom, rgba(126, 213, 111, 0.8), rgba(23, 133, 96, 0.8)), url(../img/hero.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  /*image adapts to the screen*/
  background-position: top;
  /* top of the image stays the same  whatever the screen size*/
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 70vh, 0 100%);
  position: relative;
}

.logo-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4rem;
  left: 4rem;
}

.logo {
  height: 3.5rem;
}

.text-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.heading-primary {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  /*part behind the element gets hidden*/
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.heading-primary-main {
  display: block;
  font-size: 6rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 3.5rem;
  animation-name: left;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  /* animation-iteration-count: 2;
        animation-delay: 2; */
}

.heading-primary-sub {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 2.1rem;
  animation: left 1s ease-out;
}

@keyframes right {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(10rem);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(-1rem);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}

@keyframes left {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-10rem);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(1rem);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}

@keyframes button {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(2rem);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}

.btn-animated {
  animation: button 0.5s ease-out 0.75s;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 1.5rem 4rem;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* x-axis y-axis blur color */
}

.btn:active {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.btn-white {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #777777;
}

.btn::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.btn-white::after {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.btn:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.4);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<header class="header">
  <div class="logo-box">
    <img src="img/logo-white.png" alt="Logo Natours" class="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="text-box">
    <h1 class="heading-primary">
      <span class="heading-primary-main">Outdoors</span>
      <span class="heading-primary-sub">Where life happens</span>
    </h1>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-white btn-animated">Discover Our Tours</a>
  </div>
</header>
<div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesn't work like that. You need media queries in order to set different font sizes based on screen width.

I.e. you need to tell your browser that when the screen is some width or wider (or smaller), change the font size to Y.

This is for when you want the font size to work for everything **above** 601px

```
@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  div.example {
    font-size: 80px;
  }
}
```

This is for when you want the font size to work for everything **below** 601px

```
@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  div.example {
    font-size: 80px;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have used rem here and I am currently following an Advanced CSS  course on Udemy by  Jonas Schmedtmann in which he implements the above code and everything works fine, fonts, and elements scale according to the screen size, why isn't it working for me.

Comment: hi sorry sorry to necro your question, did you manage to fix that issue?